# RxJS Observables and a wheel event

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I was wondering if anyone could help me theorize a solution. I create an Observable from a wheel event, prevent the default action, throttle it by 200ms, map deltaY (which I can use to determine direction), and then I share it.

My problem is that it emits more values than I need creating a situation where my subscribers continue to fire even after the desired action has occurred. I'm new to RxJS so bear with me but... Is there a way for me to take the "first" value emitted in a series of values within say X amount of time passed and not have the observable complete?

Below is the code.

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';

const wheel$ = fromEvent(document, 'wheel')
    .pipe(
        tap((event) => event.preventDefault()),
        // throttleTime(200), /* I have tried throttling and debouncing but that doesn't work - values will continue to be emitted */
        map((event) => event.deltaY),
        share()
    )

 // handles scrolling down //
 wheel$.pipe(filter((val) => val > 0))
     .subscribe((event) => {
         if (this.props.isScrolling) return
         this.scrollDown();
     })
```

Comment: That's interesting. I tried it and it also didn't work for me, but when I change the event from wheel to click then `throttleTime` works.

Comment: My bad, file must not have been saved, refreshing Stackblitz worked. Take a look at the console log [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nr6zzr) while scrolling in the app.

Comment: @SamHerrmann Thank you for taking time to work this out. I looked at your Stackblitz... if you execute a pronounced scroll, a 2nd event will trickle in which doesn't solve this.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be "bufferCount()"

```
of(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).pipe(
  bufferCount(3)
).subscribe(data => console.log(data) )
```

would create packages of 3 signals. So the Events would be

```
[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]
```

Or "throttleTime(xy)", than it will put the first signal through, will ignore for "xy" milliseconds every other signal, and then give the next signal a chance.

```
interval(500).pipe(
  throttleTime(2000)
).subscribe(data => console.log(data) )
```

will result in something like

```
1 // ignore everything the next 2 seconds
5 // ignore everything the next 2 seconds
9 // ignore everything the next 2 seconds
...
```

warm regards

Comment: bufferCount is no good here either. Basically the issue is the wheel event will cause the observable to emit about 20 - 50 consecutive events in one burst. So, my subscriber will execute but because events are still flooding in the subscriber will continue to get triggered.

Comment: Not exactly. Your subscriber would get less events. But in those events the information is more packed. This is good if your subscribers do want to have the control over what and how much they want to process. And you as provider define how often they get an update. --- When accept to ignore information, then try "throttle" ( https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/throttle.html )

Comment: Thank you! I'm still trying to wrap my head around reactive programming but your comment is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Found this question while looking for a solution.
I went with a switchMap

```
fromEvent(el, 'wheel').pipe(
  switchMap(e => 
    concat(
      //wrap the original event, which fires immediately
      of({kind: 'ON_WHEEL', e}),
      // fire a onWheelEnd after a 200ms delay
      // this event is unsubscribed by the switchMap if a new event comes in
      // before the delay
      of({kind: 'ON_WHEEL_END}).pipe(delay(200))
    )
  )
)
```